# problem releasing android app on play store that requieres sms and call permissions, anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Tags: android-studio, sms, app-store, call, android-permissions

i am trying to release my app of app store , i am using send_sms and call-phone permissions . i am getting this error that my app is rejected .

> Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Permissions
>   policy. Before submitting your app for another review, read through
>   the policy and make sure your app is in compliance.

Answer (score 0):

For send_sms and call-phone permissions,you have to add these usage permissions in android manifest as well as take permissions from the user manually.

You can do this by writing the following code:-

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,Manifest.permission.WRITE_SMS)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Permission is not granted }
```

If permission is granted app will continue,otherwise exit the app.